# Consume secure REST API in cross-platform native app using Xamarin

Tags: rest, xamarin, firebase

Q1: Can a native cross-platform mobile app (Android/iOS/Windows) developed in Xamarin call a web service via a **secure** REST API (https) ?

Q2: If yes, are such calls (when compiled by Xamarin) made 'natively' or made through a webview? In other words, would there be any difference in the app's capability - can the app work as a background service etc as well as a native app?

---

Note #1: I've searched & found Xamarin documentation for web services: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/
 but there is no specific mention of https. May be the answer is there in the docs, but I'm unable to find/understand.

Note #2: One example of a secure REST-ful service would be Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Yes, you can.

Q2: No, no need to use webview. You can use HttpClient class for example or RestSharp library (you can found it in Xamarin components - [RestSharp](https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp))

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firebase which saves your app data in the cloud
you can find more [here](https://www.firebase.com/) and then use [Firesharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseSharp/) to access your data in c# code.